# Designing Regular Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I've run into a bit of an issue designing RegEx in C#. I have to parse a text document that has multiple urls embedded in it, and I have to extract those

```
...url=http://www.cnn.com?id=abc,def&system=2&mode=2&quality=ade,url=http://www.bbc.com...
```

(^ I've added ellipsis to show that its part of content, ... won't actually be in the text)

The begining part is easy as I can start regex with 'url=', however, I can't come up with a way of ending the match

```
RegEx = (?<IgnoreFirst>[,]url=)(?<Url>[^,]+)
```

This regex stop at first comma - so just after 'abc' and doesn't return the entire url

```
RegEx = (?<IgnoreFirst>[,]url=)(?<Url>[^,]+)(?<IgnoreSecond>url)
```

This doesn't work either because the match stops at first comma and then looks for 'url', which it couldn't find. From some of the reading I've done it seems like its an issue of backtracking etc, so if anyone can help me out with the correct regex, that'd be great!

PS. while we're at it, if I wanted to extract url just before &quality, how would I do that?

Comment: As a side-note, download Expresso (free app). It lets you build and test .Net RegEx (not JScript RegEx) interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using something like this:

```
RegEx = url=(?<Url>.+?)(?=,url|$)
```

The lookahead at the end will force matching to stop either at the next `",url"` or at the end of the string or line.

Comment: .+? - what does ? do in this?

Comment: It makes the `+` operator non-greedy, so that it stops matching on the first occurrence of `,url`. Otherwise, it would match until the end of string.